# Image Flip algorithm in C

Tags: optimization, c, image

This is the algorithm I am using to flip an image in-place. Though it works perfectly, I would like if any one can spot any potential problems or offer any points on improvement and optimizations.

```
/**
 * pixels_buffer - Pixels buffer to be operated
 * width - Image width
 * height - Image height
 * bytes_per_pixel - Number of image components, ie: 3 for rgb, 4 rgba, etc...
 **/
void flipVertically(unsigned char *pixels_buffer, const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height, const int bytes_per_pixel)
{
    const unsigned int rows = height / 2; // Iterate only half the buffer to get a full flip
    const unsigned int row_stride = width * bytes_per_pixel;
    unsigned char* temp_row = (unsigned char*)malloc(row_stride);

    int source_offset, target_offset;

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++)
    {
        source_offset = rowIndex * row_stride;
        target_offset = (height - rowIndex - 1) * row_stride;

        memcpy(temp_row, pixels_buffer + source_offset, row_stride);
        memcpy(pixels_buffer + source_offset, pixels_buffer + target_offset, row_stride);
        memcpy(pixels_buffer + target_offset, temp_row, row_stride);
    }

    free(temp_row);
    temp_row = NULL;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't cast the result from `malloc` in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
source_offset = rowIndex * row_stride;
target_offset = (height - rowIndex - 1) * row_stride;

memcpy(temp_row, pixels_buffer + source_offset, row_stride);
memcpy(pixels_buffer + source_offset, pixels_buffer + target_offset, row_stride);
memcpy(pixels_buffer + target_offset, temp_row, row_stride);
```

could be written:

1. with `const` variables
2. without any duplicated evaluation of `pixels_buffer + [source/target]_offset`

doing something like:

```
unsigned char* source = pixels_buffer + rowIndex * row_stride;
unsigned char* target = pixels_buffer + (height - rowIndex - 1) * row_stride;
memcpy(temp_row, source, row_stride);
memcpy(source,   target, row_stride);
memcpy(target,   temp_row, row_stride);
```

Also, a different way to do would be to initialize

```
source = pixels_buffer
```

and

```
target = pixels_buffer + (height - 1) * row_stride
```

and to increment/decrement them by `row_stride` at each iteration.

**Edit:** if you go for this option, you might be able to use this for the stopping condition of your loop.

Answer (score 9):

A few comments:

- you use signed/unsigned types inconsistently. Your `width` and `height` are
  unsigned, while all other integers are signed.  If you are using unsigned
  types because the values can never be negative, then the same applies to all
  integers in the function and, by that reasoning, they should all be unsigned
  (`size_t` is a common type used for sizes).  There are arithmetic errors that
  can occur with mixed signed and unsigned arithmetic, so you should turn on
  conversion warnings (eg `-Wconversion` for `gcc`).
- your naming is inconsistent.  The function and the variable `rowIndex` use
  "camel-case", while the other variables don't.
- the return from `malloc` should not be cast in C (C++ requires casting).
- `source_offset` and `target_offset` should be defined at the point of first
  use (ie. within the loop).  There is no performance penalty for defining a
  variable within a loop in C.
- there is no check for success from `malloc`

Here is a slightly simplified version of the function

```
void flip_vertically(unsigned char *pixels, const size_t width, const size_t height, const size_t bytes_per_pixel)
{
    const size_t stride = width * bytes_per_pixel;
    unsigned char *row = malloc(stride);
    unsigned char *low = pixels;
    unsigned char *high = &pixels[(height - 1) * stride];

    for (; low < high; low += stride, high -= stride) {
        memcpy(row, low, stride);
        memcpy(low, high, stride);
        memcpy(high, row, stride);
    }
    free(row);
}
```

You can see that I have changed some types, shortened variable names (it is a
short function so short names are appropriate) and simplified the way buffer
offsets are calculated to just addition/subtraction.

Answer (score 4):

Just a quick addition to something these already great answers stated but somewhat glossed over.  Originally this question had the C++ tag in it.  I'm assuming because of this line:

```
unsigned char* temp_row = (unsigned char*) malloc(row_stride);
```

that you are compiling this C code as C++ code.  **Don't do that.**  While the languages seem very similar and the compiler you are using will probably allow it, it is a bad habit to form.  One of the main reasons not to do this is that you won't get certain warnings that you would normally get by compiling this as C code, meaning right now there could be certain vulnerabilities and bugs in your application.

I speak from personal experience.

Answer (score 3):

Just some quick things:

- `unsigned int width` doesn't need to be `const` since it's passed-by-value.  But that's not really significant as the compiler will optimize away the `const` if needed.
- Prefer [`size_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c) for types representing sizes.  It's also useful for loop counters as you'll be able to loop through any size of data supported by your computer.  However, you'll receive type-matching warnings if your counter and size types are not *both* signed or unsigned.  In this case, using `int` (which is a *signed* type) will cause such warnings if the size type is *unsigned*.